# SQL query to get the record which is not a maximum or a minimum

Tags: sql

I have below 2 tables : `STUDENTS, SUBJECTS`

```
**STUDENTS**

ID NAME SUBJECT
1  JOHN  A
2  JANE  A
3  TOM  B
4  TIM  C
5  CHRI  C
6  APE  C

**SUBJECTS**

ID NAME
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

In above Students table, I have `A repeated 2 times, B once (this is minimum) and C - 3 times(This is maximum)`

How to write a query that just gets the subject name that is neither maximum nor minimum.

In the above sample data my output should be `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select subject
from (select subject, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt,
             min(count(*)) over () as min_cnt
      from t
      group by subject
     ) s
where cnt not in (max_cnt, min_cnt);
```

Comment: @gocode . . . You are not the OP and this answer is almost a year old.  If you have a question, you should ask it as a *new* question.  Apparently this worked for the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach:

```
SELECT SUBJECT
FROM STUDENTS
GROUP BY SUBJECT
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(*) < 3
```

Comment: Did you actually test this?  All it will do is return students who have exactly 2 rows of data...

Comment: Yes, I did. If once is minimum and thrice is maximum, isn't that what is expected? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maximum and minimum can be different than 3 and 1 in different test cases.